# Create and insert data into Objects in Sales Force?

Tags: object, salesforce, insertion

I want to create and insert data into a Sales Force Object. How can I do that in the Sales Force free trial console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the ListView's **select** that has the option "**Create New...**".

I recommend you to read this [official](https://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_agent_console_cheatsheet.pdf) doc

> Create records From the New drop-down list, select any object to create a new record. New record pages display in the detail view.